# How to parse multi record XML file ues XML::Simple in Perl

Tags: perl, xml-parsing, xml-simple

My data.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<catalog>
  <cd country="UK">
    <title>Hide your heart</title>
    <artist>Bonnie Tyler</artist>
    <price>10.0</price>
  </cd>
  <cd country="CHN">
    <title>Greatest Hits</title>
    <artist>Dolly Parton</artist>
    <price>9.99</price>
  </cd>
  <cd country="USA">
    <title>Hello</title>
    <artist>Say Hello</artist>
    <price>0001</price>
  </cd>
</catalog>
```

my test.pl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

   # use module
   use XML::Simple;
   use Data::Dumper;

   # create object
   $xml = new XML::Simple;

   # read XML file
   $data = $xml->XMLin("data.xml");

   # access XML data
   print "$data->{cd}->{country}\n";
   print "$data->{cd}->{artist}\n";
   print "$data->{cd}->{price}\n";
   print "$data->{cd}->{title}\n";
```

Output:

```
Not a HASH reference at D:\learning\perl\t1.pl line 16.
```

Comment: I googled and found the article(handle single xml record). 
http://www.go4expert.com/forums/showthread.php?t=812
I tested with the article code, it works quite well on my laptop.

Then I created my practice code above to try to access multiple record. but failed. How can I fix it? Thank you.

Comment: There are some handy tips here: http://www.perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=218480

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Always `use strict;`, always `use warnings;` Don't quote complex references like you're doing. You're right to `use Dumper;`, it should have shown you that `cd` was an array ref - you have to specificity which cd.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

# use module
use XML::Simple;
use Data::Dumper;

# create object
my $xml = new XML::Simple;

# read XML file
my $data = $xml->XMLin("file.xml");

# access XML data
print $data->{cd}[0]{country};
print $data->{cd}[0]{artist};
print $data->{cd}[0]{price};
print $data->{cd}[0]{title};
```

Comment: Thanks for detail dissection.

Answer (score 2):

If you do `print Dumper($data)`, you will see that the data structure does not look like you think it does:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'cd' => [
                  {
                    'country' => 'UK',
                    'artist' => 'Bonnie Tyler',
                    'price' => '10.0',
                    'title' => 'Hide your heart'
                  },
                  {
                    'country' => 'CHN',
                    'artist' => 'Dolly Parton',
                    'price' => '9.99',
                    'title' => 'Greatest Hits'
                  },
                  {
                    'country' => 'USA',
                    'artist' => 'Say Hello',
                    'price' => '0001',
                    'title' => 'Hello'
                  }
                ]
        };
```

You need to access the data like so:

```
print "$data->{cd}->[0]->{country}\n";
print "$data->{cd}->[0]->{artist}\n";
print "$data->{cd}->[0]->{price}\n";
print "$data->{cd}->[0]->{title}\n";
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what has been said by Evan, if you're unsure if you're stuck with one or many elements, [ref()](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/ref.html) can tell you what it is, and you can handle it accordingly:

```
my $data = $xml->XMLin("file.xml");

if(ref($data->{cd}) eq 'ARRAY')
{
   for my $cd (@{ $data->{cd} })
   {
      print Dumper $cd;
   }
}
else # Chances are it's a single element
{
   print Dumper $cd;
}
```