# Perl XML edit for multi-register nested tags

Tags: perl, xml-parsing

I have a nested XML tags and need to append PF for ExternalId in Product XML

Input XML:

```
<Products>
    <Product>
      <ExternalId>317851</ExternalId>
    </Product>
    <Product>
      <ExternalId>316232</ExternalId>
    </Product>
    <Product>
      <ExternalId>13472</ExternalId>
    </Product>
</Products>
```

Desired output result:

```
   <Products>
        <Product>
          <ExternalId>PF317851</ExternalId>
        </Product>
        <Product>
          <ExternalId>PF316232</ExternalId>
        </Product>
        <Product>
          <ExternalId>PF13472</ExternalId>
        </Product>
    </Products>
```

I have tried using XML Simple.

Comment: There are many questions about parsing XML on StackOverflow.com, have you looked around?

Comment: yes, I have looked around and tested quite few of them as well.

Comment: Then perhaps you should go with the most successful of those tests and ask why it did not work instead.

Comment: I have tried the below links http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2970845/how-to-parse-multi-record-xml-file-ues-xmlsimple-in-perl?rq=1 (as I have array) and outputted as per the below link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1327720/in-perl-how-can-i-change-an-element-in-an-xml-file-without-changing-the-format. XML remains same couldn't see change in value for ExteralId.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way using the module `XML::Twig`.

Content of `script.pl`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use warnings;
use strict;
use XML::Twig;

{
    my $twig = XML::Twig->new( 

        twig_handlers => {
            'Product/ExternalId' => sub {
                $_->prefix( 'PF' );
            }   
        },  

        pretty_print => 'indented',

    )->parsefile( shift )->print;
}
```

Run it like:

```
perl-5.14.2 script.pl xmlfile
```

That yields:

```
<Products>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
  <Product>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
    <ExternalId>PF317851</ExternalId>                                                                                                                                                                                                        
  </Product>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
  <Product>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
    <ExternalId>PF316232</ExternalId>                                                                                                                                                                                                        
  </Product>
  <Product>
    <ExternalId>PF13472</ExternalId>
  </Product>
</Products>
```

---

**UPDATE**: To print to a file I've added two modifications, one line to open the output file, and the `print` method with the filehandle of the output file to print as argument

It results in:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use warnings;
use strict;
use XML::Twig;

die qq|Usage: perl $0 <input-xml> <output-xml>\n| unless @ARGV == 2;

open my $ofh, '>', pop or die qq|ERROR: Cannot open output file\n|;

{
    my $twig = XML::Twig->new( 

        twig_handlers => {
            'Product/ExternalId' => sub {
                $_->prefix( 'PF' );
            }   
        },  

        pretty_print => 'indented',

    )->parsefile( shift )->print( $ofh );
}
```

And it is invoked like:

```
perl-5.14.2 script.pl xmlfile outfile
```

Comment: Thanks Birei, I don't have Twig installed and my available libraries are   XML::LibXML, XML::NamespaceSupport, XML::Parser, XML::RegExp, XML::SAX, XML::Simple

Comment: I have installed XML::Twig and could see the result in logs, how could we write the result to a file?

Comment: `perl script.pl input > output` perhaps?

Comment: I have tried and receiving a warning(Useless use of numeric gt (>) in void context), I could see output is writing to the log file but not to a file

Comment: @user1970783: I think that @TLP means to run that command from shell. Out of the `perl` script.

Comment: My requirement is to run inside the perl script(I have requirements in the perl script)..

Comment: Found the solution to output to a file (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9885732/how-to-create-xml-with-xmltwig-containg-a-namespace-declaration-and-prefixed-n), Many Thanks TLP and Birei

Comment: @user1970783: Happy you found it. I was working editing my solution, I will post it in some minutes as an update.